# How do I get query string value

Tags: javascript

I need to grab only the value 60408571 from the following url:

http://www.domain.com/ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId=60408571&this-is-a-page-title-that-goes-here

So far, I've successfully been able to grab everything after `?ProductId=`, but this returns:

`60408571&this-is-a-page-title-that-goes-here`

The JavaScript I'm currently using is:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ProductId") > -1) {
    s.prop14 = window.location.search.replace("?ProductId=", "");
}
```

I only want to grab the numerical value if the page the user is on is a page with ProductId in the url.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A simple search may be helpful: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tom. I modified my code, based on the reference Tom provided, and I now have:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("ProductId") > -1) {
    //s.prop14 = window.location.search.replace("?ProductId=", "");
    s.prop14 = getParameterByName('ProductId');
}
```

Works great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL won't change you can also do this way:

```
var productId = findProductId(window.location.query);

function findProductId(url){
    return url.split('&')[0].split('=')[1];
}
```